# How to send people in the vicinity a notification to download my app?

Tags: android

I am developing an app for my shop.

I need to send every customer notification when they enter my shop to download my app.

It can be through Wi-Fi, SMS, or Bluetooth.

Comment: I think there is no way to send unless they have your app installed in their devices. I am not sure, how you can do it through SMS, since you don't know your Customer numbers. Again, they might carry different mobile device, how are you going to know whether that is android device?

Comment: actually not a question for stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do in any way programmatically because it's interfering into personal space:) The best thing you can do is to place a poster with QR code on the wall.

The technical problem is that in every case (Wi-Fi, Bluetooth, SMS) the client has to approve that he wants to communicate with you. (connecting to a network, pairing devices, etc.). You can't just sent information all the devices in certain area. Think what would have happened if you could:)

Comment: Excellent solution. And it kind of answers the question. As it is notifying them to download the app, with easy way to find it on app store. :)

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to do this.  It is a little bit of a chicken and egg thing.

If they had your app already, you could send them a notification easily.  But since they don't have your app installed, you have no line of communication with them.

If you could send notifications to any phone, this could be used very maliciously (like every time I pass a certain business, they could spam my notification bar with invitations to download an app).

Bottom line, you will not be able to send a notification to anyone until they have installed your app.  I am quite certain of this.

There are likely 3rd party options for this (maybe tied into UrbanAirship?).